# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent relationship non-object result

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I want show $post->category->cat_name but I have an error Trying to get property of non-object!

Model : Category

```
class Category extends \Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}
```

Model Post

```
class Post extends \Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

public function category(){

        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function comments(){

        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }

}
```

PostsController

```
public function show($id)
{
$post = Post::find($id);
return View::make('posts.show',compact('post'));

    }
}
```

In View $post->post_name works.

$post->user->username works

$post->comments->content works

but $post->category->cat_name doesn't works

And I can do CRUD with categories.

So I think there is a probleme with my model Category but i don't understand

Comment: can you access $post->category?

Comment: Is the foreign key column called `posts.category_id`? Can it have `null` values?